# React app build failed. Error: [BABEL] /app/src/index.js: Cannot find module './data/corejs3-shipped-proposals.json'

Tags: reactjs, docker, build, babeljs

I have a legacy dockerized React app that fails when 'docker compose up' is run.

React version: 16.12.0
node version: 14.19.1
Docker version: 23.0.4
Last time build was successful: Apr 18, 2023 5:47pm GMT+0200
Current time - build fails: Apr 29, 2023 10:41pm GMT+0200

Error comes at:
**docker compose up**

1.FROM node:14.19.1 as build
2.WORKDIR /app
3.COPY package.json /app/package.json
4.RUN npm install --silent --legacy-peer-deps
5.COPY . /app
6.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT} \ **npm run build**

**Error: [BABEL] /app/src/index.js: Cannot find module './data/corejs3-shipped-proposals.json'**

Somewhere a breaking change must have been introduced by an update in the last 11 days, maybe babel. Can you help me find the problem?